# key from std::map won't be passed to function parameter

Tags: c++, stdmap

I am writing c functions to c++ std::map.
One of those functions, getKey, tries to get a certain key from an object of std::map and passes it to a parameter in order to be used later.

but after function call, the parameter does not have anything in it.

I could not figure out why.
Any advice would be highly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using hashtable_t = std::map<std::string, int64_t>;

hashtable_t* initializeTable()
{
    return new hashtable_t();
}

size_t getTableSize(hashtable_t* table)
{
    return table->size();
}

bool addTableEntry(hashtable_t* table, const char* key, int64_t value)
{
    // std::cout << "key: " << key << " value: " << value << std::endl;
    const auto [iter, success] = table->insert(std::pair(key, value));
    return success;
}

size_t getKey(hashtable_t* table, int64_t seq, char* key)
{
    int64_t i=0;
    for(auto iter=table->begin(); iter!=table->end(); ++iter)
    {
        if (i == seq)
        {
            key = iter->first;
            return iter->first.size();
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}

void destroyTable(hashtable_t* table)
{
    delete table;
}

int main()
{
    bool success;
    size_t size;
    int64_t value;
    size_t length;

    hashtable_t* table = initializeTable();

    success = addTableEntry(table, "aaa", 111);
    success = addTableEntry(table, "bbb", 222);
    success = addTableEntry(table, "ccc", 485);


    size = getTableSize(table);
    std::cout << "Size: " << size << std::endl;

    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        char* key = nullptr;
        length = getKey(table, i, key);
        std::cout << "length: " << length << " key: " << key << std::endl;
    }


    destroyTable(table);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getKey` doesn't use the `key` parameter at all so it isn't surprising it doesn't change.

Comment: There was a typo and fixed.

Comment: OT: It is misleading calling the type `hashtable_t`. Maps aren't implemented as hash tables (unordered maps are), maps are basically binary search trees under the hood.

Comment: @Seong `key = iter->first;` is not legal.

Comment: Aside1: `hashtable_t` is a terrible alias for an ordered tree based map. Did you mean to use `std::unordered_map`? Aside2: You don't need `new`, you can have a `hashtable_t` as a local variable. Aside3: `initializeTable`, `getTableSize` and `destroyTable` really don't need to exist. Aside4: C++ has never required you to declare local variables at the top of a function. It is *much* clearer to define variables at the point you initialise them.

Comment: Aside5: Your `getKey` function is (trying to) get the ith key in the map. You could instead have the loop in main iterate over `iterator`s from the map: `for (auto it = table->begin(); it != table->end(); ++it) { key = it->first.c_str(); length = it->first.size(); /*use key, length*/ }`

Comment: With `size_t getKey(hashtable_t* table, int64_t seq, char* key)` the `key` pointer is passed by value. You can change it inside the function but you're changing the local copy not the pointer outside the function. You need a reference or a double pointer to make the change visible outside. `key = iter->first;` doesn't work because the key is a `std::string`. `key = iter->first.c_str();` is closer but `key` isn't a `const char*` and even if you fix that it leaves you open to having a dangling pointer to an invalid string. This is just a bad idea, use `std::string` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your key is a `std::string` so change `getKey` to return a `std::string`.

```
std::string getKey(hashtable_t* table, int64_t seq)
{
    int64_t i=0;
    for(auto iter=table->begin(); iter!=table->end(); ++iter)
    {
        if (i == seq)
        {
            return iter->first;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return std::string();
}
```

then

```
std::string key = getKey(table, i);
```

There's a few things about your code that are strange. It's not clear why you are using a map, you aren't doing anything with it that couldn't be done more efficiently with a vector. It's also pointless to dynamically allocate the map, when you then delete it exactly as if it was a stack variable. If you want your map to have the lifetime of a stack variable, then a stack variable is what you should use.

Comment: for some reasons, I would like to get c pointer style string from std::string

Comment: @Seong What are those reasons? But in any case return the key as a `std::string` and convert it to a pointer **afterwards**.

Comment: @Seong ask a separate question about extracting a char pointer from std::string. It has nothing to do with maps